# Download Video using Vimeo API

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Is it allowed to use the vimeo API to search and download videos from vimeo?
Can you download all type of videos or only a particular category?
If I would like to download all video, do I need a special approval from them (or special account) to be able to do so?

Edit: I would like to know if it's possibile using the *current* API

Answer (score 4):

Downloading source files through the API is only available under three conditions.

1. You are the owner of the video
2. You have a PRO account
3. You are the owner of the API App.

Comment: There are some changes coming soon to this functionality. You can bypass #3 by requesting the video_files scope for your access token.

Comment: Can you share the link of code, where we have a code snippet of downloading the video